# how to make the sql database table reflect in the sqlite db when creating unit testing with Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-7

I have a database with a few database tables in mysql of my laravel 7 application.
Now am trying to do unit testing , but the problem is, is there a way to make those database tables in mysql reflect in the sqlite db that I prefer to use in phpunit ? .how to do that? ..

in the root directory I created a file and named it .env.testing
then I modified its configuration into this

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE="C:/wamp64/www/myapplication/test.sqlite"
```

when I ran the phpunit existing sample test file/suite in laravel 7,
nothing happened, the test.sqlite has no tables..what did I missed out ?

Comment: How are you populating the data in your mysql db? If you are using seeders, and migrations, just ```php artisan migrate:fresh --seed``` your unit testing db before running your tests.

Comment: So you mean i just need to pass the --seed parameter ?, do i need to put the sqlite file path in the xml config file of php unit in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you prepare your database for testing before you run your tests.

If you are using MySql locally, and want to run tests locally but use sqlite instead, just change the DB environment variables in your phpunit.xml for your sqlite db like:.

```
<php>
    ...
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <server name="DB_HOST" value="..."/>
    <server name="DB_PORT" value="..."/>
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value="..."/>
    <server name="DB_USERNAME" value="..."/>
    <server name="DB_PASSWORD" value="..."/>
    ...
</php>
```

Now to load the database before you run your tests you can update your env variables in your .env file accordingly and run `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed` and your test db will be seeded. You can switch back to your previous values until you make updates to your seeds you want reflected in your test db.

And if you are using Laravel, then you will likely be using the
`RefreshDatabase` trait, so that after each test the db will be in the same state it started at.

If you don't want to take a manual approach like this, then you can automate this process using something like [phing](https://www.phing.info/), which I have used to great success in some projects.

Comment: in the DB_DATABASE , value, should I put e.g "C:/wamp64/www/myApp/test.sqlite" ? ..or ":memory" ?

Comment: @sasori DB_DATABASE is the name of the database, ie) "laravel"